# How can I force my contact list to get updated on my Samsung Galaxy S9?

Tags: contacts, sync, android-10, google-contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I store my contacts in my Google account. I can access these contacts on my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone via the Samsung contact application. After I add a contact in my Google account via another device, how can I force my contact list to get updated on my Samsung Galaxy S9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every Android device I have worked with there was always an option to force synchronization of Google data in the settings of the account:

Open Android settings and navigate to the account list. Open the used Google account and then it's "Account sync" page (synchronization settings).

There you can enable/disable each synchronization category like Contacts and so on. And there is in the upper right corner a **three-dots-menu** which allow to "**Synch now**"

[image]